# trying to popup bootstrap model but bootstrap pop-up model is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

On a button click, I am calling the JS function and passing the data to the controller using the ajax call on ajax call I am showing the bootstrap model which is not showing. After debugger in DisplayModel Function stopped. how I can solve this issue?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateRow(@Model.manualTagVMs[i].MF_Id)">Update</button>
 var RowId = 0;
        var tagvalue = 0;
            function UpdateRow(id)
            {
                tagvalue = $("#TagVaule_" + id).val();
                RowId = id;
                DisplayModal();
            }

            function DisplayModal()
            {
                debugger;
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                     url: '@Url.Action("Update","ManualTags")',
                    data: {
                        id: RowId,
                        value: tagvalue,
                     },

                    success: function(data)
                    {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                     },

                });

            }
```

Comment: are you getting a success response properly ? try alerting something inside the success block

Comment: no when the ajax call starts function stopped working there

Comment: remove last comma.